# Laravel Mail issue while testing

Tags: php, laravel, email, testing

I've encountered a problem while testing:

I try to test the Sending of a Mail with the Laravel Mail::fake() like this:

```
/** @test */
public function an_activation_mail_gets_send_on_registration()
{
    Mail::fake();

    Mail::to('john@example.com')->send(new TestMail());

    Mail::asserSent(TestMail::class);
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Error : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Testing\Fakes\MailFake::asserSent()
```

In my opinion its all the same like in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/mocking#mail-fake

Anyone knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be

```
 Mail::assertSent();
```

Comment: damn thats when hacking too fast in to the keyboard ^^ thx a lot

Answer (score 5):

You have misnamed the function. Try *asser**t**Sent* instead of *asserSent*.

Comment: damn thats when hacking too fast in to the keyboard ^^ thx a lot